# Discord.js smart help embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, embed

I am trying to make a help embed that creates a new field for every file in my command files folder. It keeps showing an error, and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const pagination = require('discord.js-pagination')
const { prefix } = require('../config.json').prefix;

module.exports = {
    name: "help", //.ping
    description: "Help command.",
    use: `${prefix}help`,

    async run (bot, message, args) {
        const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Help')
            .setDescription(`Prefix: ${prefix}`)
            for (const thing of require('../commands')) {
                .addField();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change .addField() to embed1.addField(). That may fix it. Also there is a max of 25 fields. Also try adding some arguments to add add field such as the text inside and the title of the field so like addField('test', 'test'). IDK what your error is so these are the possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is correct, this should do it:

```js
async run (bot, message, args) {
    const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Help')
        .setDescription(`Prefix: ${prefix}`);

    for (const thing of require('../commands')) {
        embed1.addField();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using the setup available on the [discordjs.guide site](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling). It means, you already have a collection of commands available on `client.commands` or `bot.commands`. It holds all the data you'll need.

Collections have a [`map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) method that returns a new array. You can use it to iterate over the `commands` and return a new [field object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/EmbedFieldData) (an object with a `name` and `value` prop). Once you have this array, you can use the [`.addFields`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addFields) method that (unlike `.addField`) accepts an array of fields.

The problem with this is that the maximum number of fields is 25. If you have more than 25 commands, you need to send them in different embeds. You've already imported `discord.js-pagination` that allows you to provide an array of embeds and then it handles all the difficult work. But you still need to make sure that there are no more than 25 fields.

To solve this, you can chunk the original array to new ones with a maximum of 25 items. I've written a helper function for you that does this. It returns an array of arrays.

Now, you can iterate over the chunks and create a new embed object for each and set up pagination.

Check out the code below:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const pagination = require('discord.js-pagination');
const { prefix } = require('../config.json').prefix;

module.exports = {
  name: 'help', //.ping
  description: 'Help command.',
  use: `${prefix}help`,

  async run(bot, message, args) {
    const MAX_FIELDS = 25;
    // iterate over the commands and create field objects
    const fields = bot.commands.map((command) => ({
      name: 'Command',
      value: `${command.name}\n${command.description}\n${command.use}`,
    }));

    // if there is less than 25 fields, you can safely send the embed
    // in a single message
    if (fields.length <= MAX_FIELDS)
      return message.channel.send(
        new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Help')
          .setDescription(`Prefix: ${prefix}`)
          .addFields(fields),
      );

    // if there are more, you need to create chunks w/ max 25 fields
    const chunks = chunkify(fields, MAX_FIELDS);
    // an array of embeds used by `discord.js-pagination`
    const pages = [];

    chunks.forEach((chunk) => {
      // create a new embed for each 25 fields
      pages.push(
        new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Help')
          .setDescription(`Prefix: ${prefix}`)
          .addFields(chunk),
      );
    });

    pagination('some message', pages);
  },
};

// helper function to slice arrays
function chunkify(arr, len) {
  let chunks = [];
  let i = 0;
  let n = arr.length;

  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, (i += len)));
  }

  return chunks;
}
```